# Query Base de Datos relacional en PostgreSQL con sub-consulta guardando el resultado en un array

Tags: array, base-de-datos, postgresql, bucles

estoy haciendo una consulta a una base de datos relacional para generar una vista necesito que todos los datos referentes a un id se muestren en una sola fila, por ejemplo, tengo 1 paciente, que tiene una cita medica, tiene 1 muestra de sangre y presenta X cantidad de sintomas.
Necesito que sea en 1 sola consulta a la base de datos porque por el codigo del sistema puedo hacerlo normalmente, el problema es que la espera se hace eterna porque hay mas de 1000 pacientes y cada paciente tiene una cantidad indeterminada de sintomas.

El query que tengo es el siguiente:

`SELECT pacientes.nroficha, citas.id AS id_cita, citas.tipo, pacientes.apellidos, pacientes.nombres, pacientes.nacionalidad, pacientes.cedula, pacientes.sexo, extraedad(pacientes.fechanaciemiento, citas.fecha) AS edad, ocupacion.descripcion AS ocupacion, (traerestado(citas.idparroquia, institucionmedica.idestado))::text AS estado, institucionmedica.distrito, filtrarinstitucion(institucionmedica.descripcion) AS desinstitucion, citas.fechainiciosintomas, tomamuestra.fecha AS fechatoma, citas.fecha AS fecharecepcion, tomamuestra.fechaingreso AS fechareceplab, muestras.descripcion AS desmuestra, examenes.descripcion AS desexamen, resultadovirologia.campos[2] AS resultado, (SELECT max(examenesconclusiones.identificador) AS identificardor FROM examenesconclusiones WHERE ((examenesconclusiones.idconclusiones = resultadovirologia.idconclusion) AND ((examenes.id)::text = (examenesconclusiones.idexamenes)::text))) AS conclusion, resultadovirologia.fechac AS fecharesultado, (SELECT max((v_estado.estado)::text) AS max FROM v_estado WHERE (v_estado.idparroquia = citas.idparroquia) LIMIT 1) AS procedencia, (SELECT max((v_estado.parroquia)::text) AS max FROM v_estado WHERE (v_estado.idparroquia = citas.idparroquia) LIMIT 1) AS parroquiades, (SELECT max((v_estado.municipio)::text) AS max FROM v_estado WHERE (v_estado.idparroquia = citas.idparroquia) LIMIT 1) AS municipiodes, citas.direccion, citas.entrevista, examenes.idsecciones, ARRAY[(SELECT v_detcaracteristicas.caract FROM v_detcaracteristicas WHERE ((v_detcaracteristicas.idcita = citas.id) AND (v_detcaracteristicas.idtipo = 3))),(SELECT v_detcaracteristicas.valor FROM v_detcaracteristicas WHERE ((v_detcaracteristicas.idcita = citas.id) AND (v_detcaracteristicas.idtipo = 3)))] AS sintomas FROM (((((((((citas JOIN tomamuestra ON ((citas.id = tomamuestra.idcita))) JOIN pacientes ON ((citas.nroficha = pacientes.nroficha))) JOIN institucionmedica ON ((citas.idinstitucionmedica = institucionmedica.id))) JOIN muestras ON (((tomamuestra.idmuestra)::text = (muestras.id)::text))) JOIN asignacionexamen ON (((citas.id = asignacionexamen.idcitas) AND (tomamuestra.idasignacionexamen = asignacionexamen.id)))) JOIN recepciondemuestra ON ((tomamuestra.id = recepciondemuestra.idtoma))) JOIN virologia.resultadovirologia ON ((recepciondemuestra.id = resultadovirologia.idrecepcion))) JOIN examenes ON (((asignacionexamen.idexamenes)::text = (examenes.id)::text))) JOIN ocupacion ON ((citas.idocupacion = ocupacion.id))) WHERE (((examenes.descripcion)::text = 'RTPCR SARS CoV-2'::text) AND (pacientes.nroficha = citas.nroficha)) ORDER BY pacientes.nroficha`

En el campo "sintomas":
`ARRAY[(SELECT v_detcaracteristicas.caract FROM v_detcaracteristicas WHERE ((v_detcaracteristicas.idcita = citas.id) AND (v_detcaracteristicas.idtipo = 3))),(SELECT v_detcaracteristicas.valor FROM v_detcaracteristicas WHERE ((v_detcaracteristicas.idcita = citas.id) AND (v_detcaracteristicas.idtipo = 3)))] AS sintomas` 
es donde quiero colocar el arreglo y que por cada sintoma, sea una posicion mas en el mismo, el problema es que al ejecutarlo asi obtengo el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Se que obtengo mas de una fila porque es lo que necesito, pero me gustaria que todas esas filas pudiese agregarlas a el arreglo correspondiente, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar `array_agg()`, quedaría así

```
(SELECT array_agg(((SELECT v_detcaracteristicas.caract 
                     FROM v_detcaracteristicas 
  WHERE ((v_detcaracteristicas.idcita = citas.id) 
  AND (v_detcaracteristicas.idtipo = 3))),
  (SELECT v_detcaracteristicas.valor 
  FROM v_detcaracteristicas 
  WHERE ((v_detcaracteristicas.idcita = citas.id) 
  AND (v_detcaracteristicas.idtipo = 3)))))) AS sintomas
```

tendrías un array con todos los síntomas,

```
{(caract, valor),(caract, valor),...}.
```

En cuanto al tiempo de ejecución no te puedo decir mucho sin saber la estructura de la base de datos, pero si puedes cambiar las subconsultas por JOIN verías una mejora notable.